# Complementary of a preorder relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

We have $R = (A, A, G )$ a preorder relation (reflexive and transitive) which is defined on set $A$ and $ ρ_R  = R \cap R^{-1} $ an equivalence relation through $R$. Therefore the relation $\overline{R}$ defined on the quotient set $A/ ρ_R $ through

$[a]_{ρ_R} \, \overline{R} \, [b]_{ρ_R} \iff a\,R\,b$

is well defined and represents a partial order relation on $A/ ρ_R $.
I don't understand why is that, since $ \overline{R} $ can't be reflexive or transitive.

Comment: Why do you think $\bar R$ cannot be reflexive or transitive?

Comment: Because  $ \overline{R} $ = (A, A, AxA \ G) which eliminates the reflexive property . (1,1)  cannot be in $ \overline{R} $ for example

Comment: That's not how $\bar R$ is defined in the question.

Comment: Yeah,sorry .I thought the overline was self-explanatory.The thing that really makes my brain hurt is how does a relation between 2 equivalence classes work

Comment: $\bar R = (A / \rho_R, A / \rho_R, \bar G)$ where $([a]_{\rho_R}, [b]_{\rho_R})\in \bar G \iff (a,b) \in G$.

Comment: So is it legit? Is $ \overline{R} $ a partial order relation on A/$p_R$ ?

Comment: $\bar R$ *as defined by the formula in the question* is indeed a partial order on $A/\rho_R$. Note however that it has absolutely nothing to do with a set complement.

Comment: Thank you very much . I thought $ \overline{R} $ was the complement of R .The notations in my text book can be confusing sometime .

Comment: I still can't figure out why $ \overline{R} $ is a partial order.I tried some examples and i get an equivalence relation? Can you give me a small example as a proof that $ \overline{R} $ is a partial order relation?

Comment: I'll compose an answer.

Comment: Thank you.I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me make clear that the formula in the question serves as the *definition* of $\overline R$. In particular, other than you thought, this overline notation does not denote a complement.

As an example, consider the relation "$xRy \iff$ person $x$ is at most as tall as person $y$" with the following people:

- $a=\text{Adam}$, $170~\rm cm$
- $b=\text{Barbara}$, $180~\rm cm$
- $c=\text{Charles}$, $180~\rm cm$
- $d=\text{Doris}$, $190~\rm cm$

We obviously have $aRa,aRb,aRc,aRd,bRb,bRc,bRd,cRb,cRc,cRd,dRd$.

Now $\rho_r = R \cap R^{-1}$ is the equivalence relation "$x$ is exactly as tall as $y$", with the three equivalence classes

- $[a]_{\rho_R} = \{a\}$
- $[b]_{\rho_R} = [c]_{\rho_R} = \{b,c\}$
- $[d]_{\rho_R} = \{d\}$

Now using the definition of $\overline R$, we get

- $[a]_{\rho_R} \overline R [a]_{\rho_R}$ because $aRa$.
- $[a]_{\rho_R} \overline R [b]_{\rho_R}$ because $aRb$.
- $[a]_{\rho_R} \overline R [d]_{\rho_R}$ because $aRd$.
- $[b]_{\rho_R} \overline R [b]_{\rho_R}$ because $bRb$.
- $[b]_{\rho_R} \overline R [d]_{\rho_R}$ because $bRd$.
- $[d]_{\rho_R} \overline R [d]_{\rho_R}$ because $dRd$.

This is obviously a partial order (indeed, in this case even a total order) of the three equivalence classes.

In the general case, you can see that $\overline R$ is indeed a partial order as follows:

- $\overline R$ is actually well defined (this has to be checked!): If $[a]_{\rho_R} = [b]_{\rho_R}$ and $[c]_{\rho_R} = [d]_{\rho_R}$ then we have to show that $[a]_{\rho_R} \overline R [c]_{\rho_R}$ iff $[b]_{\rho_R} \overline R [d]_{\rho_R}$.

  If $[a]_{\rho_R} = [b]_{\rho_R}$ then we have both $aRb$ and $bRa$, and from $[c]_{\rho_R} = [d]_{\rho_R}$ we get $cRd$ and $dRc$.

  Now by definition of $\overline R$, $[a]_{\rho_R} \overline R [c]_{\rho_R}$ iff $aRc$. Now thanks to transitivity of $R$, we get from $bRa$ and $aRc$ that $bRc$, and then with $cRd$ that $bRd$. The direction $bRd \implies aRc$ works analogously. But by definition of $\overline R$, $bRd \iff [b]_{\rho_R} \overline R [d]_{\rho_R}$.
- Reflexivity: Due to reflexivity of $a$, we have $aRa$, and thus by definition of $\overline R$ we get $[a]_{\rho_R}\overline R [a]_{\rho_R}$.
- Transitivity: If $[a]_{\rho_R} \overline R [b]_{\rho_R}$ and $[b]_{\rho_R} \overline R [c]_{\rho_R}$, then we have by the definition of $\overline R$ that $aRb$ and $bRc$, and thus by transitivity of $R$ we have $aRc$ which by definition of $\overline R$ means $[a]_{\rho_R} \overline R [c]_{\rho_R}$.
- Antisymmetry: If $[a]_{\rho_R} \overline R [b]_{\rho_R}$ and $[b]_{\rho_R} \overline R [a]_{\rho_R}$, then by definition of $\overline R$ we have $aRb$ and $bRa$, but that means that $a$ and $b$ are equivalent according to $\rho_R$, thus $[a]_{\rho_R} = [b]_{\rho_R}$.